# Delphi - Lenze Standard addressing - Code number conversion

Tags: delphi, numbers, delphi-xe3

From [Lenze manual](http://www.lenze.com/en/products/accessories/industrial-communication/lecom/)

```
Code number (C1, C2)
Standard addressing
The meaning of the code numbers and the assigned parameters can be obtained from
the code table (see chapter 8.2). When transmitting data, the code number are
coded as follows:
The following calculation determines the two ASCII digits from the code number
(value range: 0..6229) (value range: 48dec 127dec):
C1 = INTEGER((REMAINDER(code number/790))/10) + 48dec
C2 = REMAINDER(REMAINDER(code number/790)/10) + 
     INTEGER(code number/790) x 10 + 48dec
```

Procedure for calculating C1 and C2 from codenumber.

```
procedure pCodeNumberToC1C2(CodeNumber: Word; var C1, C2: Byte);
begin
  C1 := Byte((CodeNumber mod 790) div 10) + 48;
  C2 :=     ((CodeNumber mod 790) mod 10) + 48 + 10 * Byte(CodeNumber div 790);
end;
```

But, how to calculate it the other way without the aweful:

```
function fC1C2ToCodeNumber(iC1, iC2: Byte): Word;
var
  C1, C2: Byte;
  i: Integer;
Begin
  Result := 0;
  For i := 0 to 6229 Do Begin
    pCodeNumberToC1C2(i, C1, C2);
    if (C1 = iC1) and (C2 = iC2) Then Result := i;
  End;
  Result := cn;
End;
```

Comment: Surely `For i := 1 to 6229 Do Begin` should be `For i := 0 to 6229 Do Begin`?

Comment: Maybe.  Have not found codenumber 0 anywhere as a valid address so I simply left it out until I find the need for it.

Comment: The spec you quote seems quite clear....

Comment: Fair enough ;)  But that's very far from the point.

Comment: Why is it far from the point?

Comment: The point of the question was not if I got the ranging right in my function.
I still have not found address 0 anywhere else in the documentation and believe the range provided is incorrect.  After all address 1 is something convenient as "Operation mode" and address 2 "Par load", 3 "Par save", 4 "Op-display".  Address 0 has yet to show its presence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Let's 
N = p * 790 + q
then
c1 = 48 + q div 10
c2 = 48 + q mod 10 + 10 * p
so
p = (c2-48) div 10
q = (c2-48) mod 10 + (c1-48) * 10
```

test:

```
var
  c1, c2: Byte;
  n, p, q, t: Word;
begin
  for t := 0 to 6229 do begin
    n := t;
    pCodeNumberToC1C2(n, c1, c2);
    p := (c2-48) div 10;
    q := (c2-48) mod 10 + (c1-48) * 10;
    n := 790*p+q;
    if n <> t then
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Failed at ' + IntToStr(t))
  end;
```

Final:

```
function C1C2ToCodeNumber(C1, C2: Byte): Word;
begin
Result := ((C2 - 48) div 10) * 790 + ((C2 - 48) mod 10 + (C1 - 48) * 10);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to arithmetic you could consider a lookup table. At the cost of memory, this gives you better performance. The code looks like this:

```
const
  CodeNumberTable: array [48..126, 48..127] of Word = (
    .... code removed because of Sack Overflow post size limitation
  );

const
  MinC1 = low(CodeNumberTable);
  MinC2 = high(CodeNumberTable);
  MaxC1 = low(CodeNumberTable[MinC1]);
  MaxC2 = high(CodeNumberTable[MinC1]);

type
  EInvalidParameters = class(Exception);

function fC1C2ToCodeNumber(iC1, iC2: Byte): Word;
begin
  if not InRange(iC1, MinC1, MaxC1) then
    raise EInvalidParameters.CreateFmt(
      'iC1 (%d) must be in the range %d to %d',
      [iC1, MinC1, MaxC1]
    );
  if not InRange(iC2, MinC2, MaxC2) then
    raise EInvalidParameters.CreateFmt(
      'iC2 (%d) must be in the range %d to %d',
      [iC2, MinC2, MaxC2]
    );
  Result := CodeNumberTable[iC1, iC2];
  if Result=high(Word) then
    raise EInvalidParameters.CreateFmt(
      'CodeNumber not defined for iC1=%d, ic2=%d',
      [iC1, iC2]
    );
end;
```

I can supply the table via paste bin if you are interested.

Comment: If I ever succeed with my project there is a good chance the application will be used at old computers where saving CPU over stealing some memory can be a great advance.  Table via pastebin will be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: OK. Will be tomorrow now before I can do that.

Comment: It took me ages to type it out ;-)